# Invalid parameter number error in Codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, image, codeigniter, binary, storage

I am working on a process in Codeigniter to take a user-uploaded image (managed using the CI upload library) and insert it into a varbinary(max) field in a SQLServer database. My controller and model code are as follows.

```
if($this->upload->do_upload($upload_name)) {
    //get temp image
    $tmpName  = $config['upload_path'] . $config['file_name'];  

    // Read it into $data variable
    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'rb');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    fclose($fp);

    //insert into DB
    $this->the_model->storeImage($data, $user_id);

    //delete temp image      
    unlink($config['upload_path'] . $config['file_name']);
}

/***** Function from the_model ************/
function storePropertyImage($image_data, $user_id) {
    $my_db = $this->load->database('admin');
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO my_table (UserID, ImageData) VALUES (" . $my_db->escape($user_id) . ", " . $my_db->escape($image_data) . ")";
    $insert = $my_db->query($stmt);
    return $insert;
}
```

This all seems like it should be OK but when I run the code, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' 
in {my app path}\helpers\mssql_helper.php on line 213
```

I've done some googling on this error message and the results seem to indicate this is the result of there being a colon character in the $data value being sent to the model, making the DB think that I am trying to pass a named parameter when I am not. However I haven't been able to find any reports that match my specific use case or that have much info on how to correct the error.

I'd appreciate any insight on where I might be tripping up.

Comment: Why are you doing this `addslashes($image_data)`? `$my_db->escape()` will already properly escape the value for the query. You are double escaping.

Comment: @crypticツ Heh...that's a legacy of my fiddling around with this trying to figure out how to make it work; I initially had it with just escape(). I've updated the code to remove that.

Comment: What does `echo $stmt;` show?  Which line is line 213?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `INSERT INTO my_table (UserID, ImageData) VALUES ('8', '����\0JFIF\0\0`\0`\0\0��Exif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0VGF\0\0\0\0\0\0\0GI\0\0\0\0\02\0\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0�i\0\0\0\0\0\0\0j\0\0\0�2009:03:12 13:47:43\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0\0���\0\0\0\054\0\0��\0\0\0\054\0\0�\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\02008:03:14 13:59:26\02008:03:14 13:59:26\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0&\0\0\0\0\0\0 �\0\0\0\0\0\0\0H\0\0\0\0\0\0H\0\0\0����\0JFIF\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0C\0 (1#%(:3=<9387@H\\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\\egc��`...(and so on. long mucky string)

Comment: @RocketHazmat And the line 213 returns to the line in the CI mssql driver we're using that prepares the query for execution.

Comment: You're trying to escape a binary string.  Seems that doesn't work.  Also, that might edit the binary data, thus creating a corrupted image.  Try converting the binary string to hex before inserting it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hmm. Well, progress. :D Ran bin2hex on the value and am now getting the error "Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed." I take it this means if I'm going to use hex it needs to be a different datatype in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$image_data` is a binary string.  `->escape` may not work on it, since it may escape random bytes in it, thus leaving you with a corrupted image.  Also the binary string may contain quote characters (or other characters) that is making your query invalid.

Try to encode the binary string as hex before inserting into MySQL.  You can use PHP's [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) for this.

```
$escaped_user_id = $my_db->escape($user_id);
$hex_image = bin2hex($image_data);
$stmt = "INSERT INTO my_table (UserID, ImageData) VALUES ({$escaped_user_id}, X'{$hex_image}')";
```

The `X` in `X{$hex_image}` is how MySQL handles literal hex strings: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

If that doesn't work, you can also try [`UNHEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex).

```
$escaped_user_id = $my_db->escape($user_id);
$hex_image = bin2hex($image_data);
$stmt = "INSERT INTO my_table (UserID, ImageData) VALUES ({$escaped_user_id}, UNHEX('{$hex_image}'))";
```

**EDIT**: I didn't notice you were using MSSQL and not MySQL.  My bad.  In MSSQL, you can insert literal hex strings with `0x`.

```
$escaped_user_id = $my_db->escape($user_id);
$hex_image = bin2hex($image_data);
$stmt = "INSERT INTO my_table (UserID, ImageData) VALUES ({$escaped_user_id}, 0x{$hex_image})";
```

Comment: I'm using mssql, unfortunately, and either the DB itself or the CI driver for it doesn't seem to be playing nice with UNHEX. So I'm guessing I'm going to have to look at changing the column datatype to varchar and just storing and managing the hex values with PHP. Thanks so much...this has been helpful. :)

Comment: @rosalindwills: Ah, didn't notice you weren't using MySQL, I just kinda assumed >.>  Maybe you can use `CONVERT` to cast the hex to binary.

Comment: @rosalindwills: I found something that may help: http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/sql-server-convert-a-string-into-a-hex-string-and-back-sql-sqlserver/

Comment: Oh, awesome! :) That definitely looks promising; I will give that a shot.

Comment: @rosalindwills: I did some testing, and you don't need `CONVERT`!  Just do `0x{$hex_image}` :-)